# Excel VBA Format function does not return desired date

Tags: vba, excel, format, datepart

I have an Excel sheet with E2 = "10-Apr-16" as Custom format. And I would like to return its week number (maybe 16). The code I used (with E2 active):

```
With ActiveCell
    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    .Value = Date
End With
oneDate = Format(Range("E2").Select, "mm/dd/yyyy")
weekNumber = DatePart("ww", oneDate)
```

oneDate turned out to be 12/29/1899, and WeekNumber to be 52. What is wrong with my code???

---

Update:

I later changed code to:

```
Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "m/dd/yyyy"
oneDate = Range("E2")
oneDate = Format(Range("E2").Select, "m/dd/yyyy")
weekNumber = DatePart("ww", oneDate)
```

With this, I get 12/29/1899 as oneDate, and 52 as weekNumber.

Without the third line (or even without first line), the code will work properly and return 16 as weekNumber;

With the third line (no matter with/without first line), it still returned 12/29/1899.

I think the problem is with the code in third line, but not sure what it is. Does anybody know how I did it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code inserts the system date into ActiveCell (whichever one that happens to be), then you set oneDate to E2

I don't know entirely what you're hoping to achieve, but it seems that you can achieve what you've stated via

```
weekNumber = datepart("ww", Range("E2"))
```

As long as what's in E2 is actually a date serial number which Excel recognises as a date, and not simply text which looks like a date (an important distinction)

If weekNumber is still wrong, try

```
weekNumber = datepart("ww",date)
```

This will get the current week number, and means that E2 is not really a date as far as Excel is concerned

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems like the cause was that I format the date twice before I used datepart function. Maybe the second formatting had made the date to some serial number which would be interpreted as year 1899....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim d1 As Date
    d1 = ActiveCell.Value
    MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(d1)
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!